# saving data from Parse to an Excel file and sending it via email

Tags: ios, excel, parse-platform

Take a look at a picture I created to help you better understand the question i am asking.

[image]
Also, here is the tutorial where i got the saving of the text fields to parse:

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-save-data-parse-cloud-tutorial/

And here is the website where i got all the ios in excel information:

http:// libxl.com/download.html

It can save data to parse and also display it. Also I can manually create a .xls(excel) file and have it be sent to someone via email. All I need to do now is populate the .xls file with the data I have in parse.

Here is my .h file

```
//  DataViewController.h
//  libxl-example
//
//  Created by dmytro on 12/25/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 xlware. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
@interface DataViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dataLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) id dataObject;

- (IBAction)createExcel:(id)sender;



@end
```

Here is my .m file

```
//
//  DataViewController.m
//  libxl-example
//
//  Created by dmytro on 12/25/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 xlware. All rights reserved.
//

#import "DataViewController.h"

#include "LibXL/libxl.h"
#import "RecipeBookViewController.h"
#import "RecipeDetailViewController.h"
#import "Recipe.h"

@interface RecipeBookViewController ()

@end

@implementation RecipeBookViewController {

}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    if (self) {
        // Custom the table

        // The className to query on
        self.parseClassName = @"Recipe";

        // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
        self.textKey = @"name";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = NO;

        // The number of objects to show per page
        //self.objectsPerPage = 10;
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(refreshTable:)
                                                 name:@"refreshTable"
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)refreshTable:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    // Reload the recipes
    [self loadObjects];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"refreshTable" object:nil];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

    // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
    // and then subsequently do a query against the network.
    /*    if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
     query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
     }*/

    //    [query orderByAscending:@"name"];

    return query;
}



// Override to customize the look of a cell representing an object. The default is to display
// a UITableViewCellStyleDefault style cell with the label being the first key in the object.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RecipeCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell
    PFFile *thumbnail = [object objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
    PFImageView *thumbnailImageView = (PFImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.jpg"];
    thumbnailImageView.file = thumbnail;
    [thumbnailImageView loadInBackground];

    UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:101];
    nameLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"name"];

    UILabel *prepTimeLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:102];
    prepTimeLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"prepTime"];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Remove the row from data model
    PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [object deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        [self refreshTable:nil];
    }];
}

- (void) objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error
{
    [super objectsDidLoad:error];

    NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        Recipe *recipe = [[Recipe alloc] init];
        recipe.name = [object objectForKey:@"name"];
        recipe.imageFile = [object objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
        recipe.prepTime = [object objectForKey:@"prepTime"];
        recipe.ingredients = [object objectForKey:@"ingredients"];
        destViewController.recipe = recipe;

    }
}


@end
@interface DataViewController ()
@end
@implementation DataViewController

- (void)dealloc
{

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.dataLabel.text = [self.dataObject description];
}

- (IBAction)createExcel:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"createExcel");

    BookHandle book = xlCreateBook(); // use xlCreateXMLBook() for working with xlsx files

    SheetHandle sheet = xlBookAddSheet(book, "Sheet1", NULL);

    xlSheetWriteStr(sheet, 1, 1, "Hello World !", 0);
    xlSheetWriteNum(sheet, 4, 1, 1000, 0);
    xlSheetWriteNum(sheet, 5, 1, 2000, 0);

    FontHandle font = xlBookAddFont(book, 0);
    xlFontSetColor(font, COLOR_RED);
    xlFontSetBold(font, true);
    FormatHandle boldFormat = xlBookAddFormat(book, 0);
    xlFormatSetFont(boldFormat, font);
    xlSheetWriteFormula(sheet, 6, 1, "SUM(B5:B6)", boldFormat);

    FormatHandle dateFormat = xlBookAddFormat(book, 0);
    xlFormatSetNumFormat(dateFormat, NUMFORMAT_DATE);
    xlSheetWriteNum(sheet, 8, 1, xlBookDatePack(book, 2011, 7, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0), dateFormat);

    xlSheetSetCol(sheet, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0);

    NSString *documentPath =
    [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filename = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"out.xls"];

    xlBookSave(book, [filename UTF8String]);

    xlBookRelease(book);

    if (![MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        //Show alert that device cannot send email, this is because an email account     hasn't been setup.
    }

    else {

        //**EDIT HERE**
        //Use this to retrieve your recently saved file

        NSString *documentPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *filename = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"out.xls"];

        //**END OF EDIT**

        NSString *mimeType = @"application/vnd.ms-excel"; //This should be the MIME type for els files. May want to double check.
        NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filename];
        NSString *fileNameWithExtension = @"out.xls"; //This is what you want the file to be called on the email along with it's extension:

        //If you want to then delete the file:
        NSError *error;
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filename error:&error])
            NSLog(@"ERROR REMOVING FILE: %@", [error localizedDescription]);


        //Send email
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailMessage = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [mailMessage setMailComposeDelegate:self];
        [mailMessage addAttachmentData:fileData mimeType:mimeType fileName:fileNameWithExtension];
        [self presentViewController:mailMessage animated:YES completion:nil];
    }


}


- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {

    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled: you cancelled the operation and no email message was queued.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved: you saved the email message in the drafts folder.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail send: the email message is queued in the outbox. It is ready to send.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail failed: the email message was not saved or queued, possibly due to an error.");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Mail not sent.");
            break;
    }

    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

The Project is almost done I just need this last bit of help

Anything will help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add the code just under //**EDIT HERE** to retrieve the data from Parse.com by using PFQuery. Please follow this https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-retrieving/iOS and modify to fit your data structure.

If you are not sure you data structure. Please log in to Parse and navigate to your Data Browser of your app. It should looks like https://parse.com/apps/YOUR_APP_NAME/collections. and then click on the field and find out the JSON data.  PFQuery will get you NSDictionary. use NSString key to look up the NSDictionary to retrieve the data you like.

Comment: If you would please take a second look at my code, you will see that I have completed what your answer states if you could please provide me with information on exporting parse fields into the excel spread sheet opposed to in a view controller.

Comment: I can't find how queryForTable hook up with self.objects, but I am assuming all your parse data should be in self.objects when I look at prepareForSegue:: method. Do you want to know how to convert your data (self.objects) into Excel Cell by using http:// libxl.com/download.html?

Comment: I suggest you generate the file by using commas as the delimiter and name it as *.xls. It will open as excel file.

Comment: Yes, I would like to know how to convert that data into an .xls spreadsheet by using the libxl download, could you possible provide me with some sample code, if you could help me with that, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am not good at libxl, I thought your problem was in Parse.com side which I am good at.